# File not Passing on ng-file-select in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass a file from html view to angular controller, for this I am using ng-file-select in the view. My view code looks like:

```
<div ng-controller="fileController">

    <input type="file" ng-model="fibQuestion.fibContentLanguage.colUploadPaperUrl" name="PaperDocUrl" ng-file-select="onPaperFileSelect($files)" onclick="this.value = null" id="forPracticalTestPaper" />

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" ng-click="PaperFileProcessing()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But here, ng-file-select="onPaperFileSelect($files)" cannot passing the file to the controllers. The controller code is :

```
app.controller('fileController',function($scope) {



    $scope.onPaperFileSelect = function ($files) {
        if ($scope.verifiedFileType($files[0].name, 'paper')) {
            $scope.saveFileLoacation = '~/UploadedFiles/PracticalTestPaperFiles/';
            $scope.yesDisable = false;
            $scope.uploadedPaper = $files;
            $('#upload-paper-file-info').text($files[0].name);
            $scope.showPaperDeleteButton = true;
        }
    };


    $scope.verifiedFileType = function (fileName, fileType) {

        var extension = (fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'), fileName.length)).toLowerCase();
        if (extension == ".pdf") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("file extension not valid for " + fileType + ". available extensions are pdf.");
            angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
            return false;
        }
    };

    $scope.PaperFileProcessing = function () {

        $scope.upload = [];
        $scope.yesDisable = true;

        var fileBank = $scope.uploadedPaper;
        console.log(fileBank);
        var status = false;
        var i = fileBank.length;
        console.log(i);         
    };    
});
```

When , I press the save button, that calls the function PaperFileProcessing(), but then,  var fileBank = $scope.uploadedPaper; is showing undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is missing some kind of "promises" to wait for file uploaded entirely, no ?
Perhaps something like that :

```
// returns a promise
upload.then(function(resp) {
  // file is uploaded successfully
  console.log('file ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'is uploaded successfully. Response: ' + resp.data);
}, function(resp) {
  // handle error
}, function(evt) {
  // progress notify
  console.log('progress: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total) + '% file :'+ evt.config.data.file.name);
});
```